# calculus resolve some complicated functions

Tags: calculus

Could you find a $f(x)$ such that

> $$\frac{F''(x+2)}{x^2}+F'(x+1)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{(x+1)^2}}$$
>   Thanks

Comment: Is your $F(x) = f(x)$ or $F(x) = \int_{x_0}^x f(t) dt$? Also
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{(x+1)^2}} = \frac{1}{|x+1|}$$
For better readability ;)

Comment: What's the context?

Comment: f(x)==F(x),and the second part is correct